# Object does not hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to learn hooks but have a problem with an object. Looks like useState doesn't treat my object as an object and I can't get hold of the second value.

```
function App() {
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState({
    fName: "",
    lName: ""
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { value, name } = event.target;

    setFullName((prevValue) => {
      if (name === "fName") {
        return {
          fName: value,
          lName: prevValue.lName
        };
      } else if (name === "lName") {
        return {
          fName: prevValue.fName,
          lname: value
        };
      }
    });
  }
  console.log(fullName.fName);
  console.log(fullName.lName);

 return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Hello {fullName.lName}</h1>
      <form>
        <input
          name="fName"
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="First Name"
          value={fullName.fName}
        />
        <input
          name="lName"
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Last Name"
          value={fullName.lName}
        />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I console.log the lName, "undefined" pops up, while fName works perfect.

Comment: It does work in this [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-morse-71fc8s?file=/src/App.js) I created. (It is the same code as yours, just a little more efficient one for me)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the `else if (name === "lName")` return statement you're returning a key named `lname` instead of `lName`.

Comment: Please don't problems caused by typos. It's unlikely that a future user has the same typo. These questions and answers aren't useful for future users. These questions should be closed and deleted.